# In apache's mod_rewrite, how can I write a RewriteCond to match the http accept header for all html types?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-headers, http-accept-header

I have the following rule in my `.htaccess` that detects if the user passes a specific host, and is asking for HTML, that I provide a specific HTML file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.domain\.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.domain\.eu$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /subdomains/example/index.html [END]

# Otherwise go to php api
```

This seemed to work, but I was getting a lot of warning logs from the php api for unmatched routes. Those routes *should* have gone to that index.html. I set up a breakpoint and found that I was getting requests with `Accept: */*`. I could reproduce this issue reliably when I would open the dev console after visiting the page in chrome (I'm not sure why chrome would send off that request... loading the source panel maybe? It results in a "Failed to load resource" error in the console)

Obviously a simple substring search that RewriteCond is doing for `text/html` won't be sufficient. I believe need to at least handle `*/*` and `text/*`, but are there some not-so-obvious accept headers? I see some RewriteCond examples of `application/xhtml+xml`. How can I write a RewriteCond to match the http accept header for all html types?

Comment: What type of requests are you intending to send to your "php api"? Who/what is sending these requests?

Comment: "but I was getting a lot of warning logs from the php api for unmatched routes" - How are these requests being sent?

Comment: Normally the frontend does fetch requests using `Accept: application/json` to `subdomain.example.com/folder/1234` to load the data without a full page refresh (using php). However, if you were go to your browser and navigate to `subdomain.example.com/folder/1234`, it should return the html page to do HTML5 Routing (using a static page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Normally the frontend does fetch requests using `Accept: application/json` to `subdomain.example.com/folder/1234` to load the data without a full page refresh (using php).

If the API accepts specific requests (mime-types and/or URL-paths) then maybe reverse the logic and route the request to your PHP API first. Other requests then default to an HTML response.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} application/json
RewriteRule ^folder/\d+$ /api.php [END]

# Otherwise default to HTML response
RewriteRule ^ /subdomains/example/index.html [END]
```

If the API only accepts URL-paths that follow a specific pattern then this should also be included in the rule (as above).

**Other notes...**

> However, if you were go to your browser and navigate to `subdomain.example.com/folder/1234`, it should return the html page to do HTML5 Routing (using a static page)

If you simply navigate to this URL in the browser then the browser *should* be including `text/html` in the `Accept` header.

Have you examined the `Referer` and `User-Agent` fields of the logged request that seemingly omitted the `text/html` mime-type from the request? Are you sure this is a user's direct request from the browser? And not bots/search engine traffic (although Googlebot typically includes `text/html` when crawling)?

Unless `text/html` is sent in the `Accept` header then you cannot be sure that the UA making the request will be able to handle an HTML response.

If a UA *only* accepts `application/xhtml+xml` (XML) then strictly speaking it's not going to accept a `text/html` response. (Typically browsers send both of these mime-types in the `Accept` header when making an arbitrary request.)

If a UA only accepts *anything* (ie. `*/*`) then that doesn't necessarily mean a `text/html` response is appropriate. Typically, I see `Accept: */*` only, for requests to embedded JS files. The same applies to requests that include `Accept: text/*` only.